# VB6 PictureBox height

Tags: image, vb6, resize, picturebox

I'm trying to export a picture from a PictureBox but the problem is with the height of the exported picture (the width working perfectly).

I also found out that VB6 border have major effect to the size of the exported picture so I set it to 0.

Just open vb6 drop a PictureBox (and rename it to myPic)...

This is my code :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()

    myPic.AutoRedraw = True

    myPic.BorderStyle = 0
    myPic.Appearance = 0
    myPic.Width = 100 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX 'WORKING PERFECTLY!!!
    myPic.Height = 100 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY 'NOT RETURN 100px !!! Why ? 93px instead 
    myPic.ScaleMode = vbPixels

    myPic.PaintPicture LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Source.bmp"), 0, 0, 100, 100
    myPic.Picture = myPic.Image

    SavePicture myPic.Picture, App.Path & "\Exported.bmp"

End Sub
```

Any Idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it works as I think you intended: it shows source.bmp in a 100x100 picturebox and exports it into a bmp of 100x100 pixels

The code I uses is:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With Picture1
    .AutoRedraw = True
    .ScaleMode = vbPixels
    .BorderStyle = 0
    .Appearance = 0
    .Width = 100 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelX 'WORKING PERFECTLY!!!
    .Height = 100 * Screen.TwipsPerPixelY 'NOT RETURN 100px !!! Why ? 93px instead
    .PaintPicture LoadPicture("c:\temp\Source.bmp"), 0, 0, 100, 100
    .Picture = .Image
    SavePicture .Picture, "c:\temp\Exported.bmp"
  End With 'Picture1
End Sub
```

I just put the .Scalemode to the top as I think that is where it belongs, but your code also works with .Scalemode where you had it.

Could you please add the picture you are trying to rescale?

For the source I used the picture below, which is 300x300 pixels:

[image]

And the result was:

[image]